# How to remove element from memory

Tags: java, element

I have loop with send screen, and when memory reaches 2 gb program stops.
How I remove sended image from memory?

```
while (true) {
            try {
                System.gc();
                img = r.createScreenCapture(rect);
                icon = new javax.swing.ImageIcon(img);
                os.writeObject(icon);
                os.flush();
                icon = null;
                System.gc();
                try {
                    Thread.currentThread().sleep(sleepInterval);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                closeAll();
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Don't. Leave this work for the GC.

Comment: This is not all your code. What classes are img & r?

Comment: Well, I would rather try to increase the heap size.. Also check that `DisableExplicitGC` has been disabled. Note : calling `System.gc()` explicitly is not a good idea

Comment: Have you tried `img.flush()`

Answer (score 0):

All run function:

```
        public void run() {
        java.awt.image.BufferedImage img = null;
        Robot r = null;
        try {
            r = new Robot();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        Dimension size = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
        javax.swing.ImageIcon icon = null;

        while (true) {
            try {
                System.gc();
                img = r.createScreenCapture(rect);
                icon = new javax.swing.ImageIcon(img);
                os.writeObject(icon);
                os.flush();
                icon = null; // coś nie działa usuwanie bo pamięć rośnie
                System.gc();
                try {
                    Thread.currentThread();
                    Thread.sleep(sleepInterval);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                closeAll();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Problem fixed. I added os.reset() after writeObject()